# How to remove "Built with SUSEStudio"? (Suse Studio)

Tags: opensuse

Does any one know how to remove "Built with SUSEStudio" logo which is used in the bootsplash, ,login Background, in the LIVE CD/DVD which built by SUSEStudio?

Comment: Don't build it with SUSEStudio?

Answer (score 1):

When you are building, if you are building in gnome, delete the software "yast2-branding-openSUSE" on the software tab and it should remove it.

Comment: what does Gnome have to do with this it?

Answer (score 0):

Download the ISO to your machine and then extract the contents and locate the following folder  /boot/animation directory.

Replace the images to your liking then rebuild the ISO and make sure that its BOOTABLE then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Simply search branding in the software part of whats installed. And remove it, there you go no more branding. Its mostly labeled something like branding-openSuSE or something like that.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Login to SuseStudio, go to software in searchbox type `branding` and remove all packages installed. Thas shall get rid of them! Have Fun!